# Firebase returning incorrect values - ionic / angular2

Tags: angular, object, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from a firebase database, the variable in question is a date. When I store the date, it stores correctly, with the correct date - but when I retrieve the date it always comes back with both of these dates at the same time:

```
{"date":{"day":"Fri Jul 21 2017 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"},"reserved":{"appointment":["1:00 
            PM","10:00 AM","2:00 PM","4:30 PM","5:30 PM","6:30 PM"]}}
```

and

```
{"date":{"day":"Fri Jul 14 2017 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"},"reserved":{"appointment":["1:00 
            PM","10:00 AM","2:00 PM"]}}
```

The `day` variable (the date) is either `Jul 14` or `Jul 21`. However, in my database I don't have any items with those values stored. Here is what my database looks like:

[image]

As you can see all of the `day` variables have `Jul 26` **NOT** `Jul 14`/`Jul 21`

Firebase is also making up the appointments too, all of the times in the `appointment` are seemingly coming from nowhere.

**UPDATE**

My firebase query looks like this - it is messing up in a very basic spot.

```
this.items = this.af.list('/appointments/' + this.username);
this.items.subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
  console.log(item.date.day);
```

It gets the two incorrect dates in the `forEach`.

Comment: show your retrieve query too.

Comment: thanks, updated - also one thing i noticed...the query happens twice...it gets July 14th then July 21st

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with my query, `this.username` was null and storing values under `null` instead of the previous one I was using.